# Develop a basic search engine using python from given csv file(sales data)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, search

[Here is the actual problem statement have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqsm9.jpg).
The sales dataset includes the following details: Ids, product name, product line (product category), brand , number of items sold in the last month and current prices.
[This is the given csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxJ2z.jpg)**The user can enter the search text in any case or in any sequence or just the partial name of product. Following guidelines should be followed always:**

•   If the search text contains name of a brand, the results should be for the same brand products only

•   If the search text contains name of a product line (category), or even an incomplete name (e.g. ‘ref’ in place of ‘refrigerator’) , the results should be for the corresponding product line (category) only

•   Out of n words in the search text, at least n-1 should exist in the product name

```
Example :

Input : Samsung Refrigerators

Output:

Top Selling  Products :

  1307    SAMSUNG REF FF 321L RT34K3953S9 3S    Refrigerators   SAMSUNG 19  29891.79
  1153    SAMSUNG REF FF 253L RT28K3023SE/HL SL 3S  Refrigerators   SAMSUNG 13  21493.38
  1474    SAMSUNG REF FF 275L RT30K3723S8/HL 3S Refrigerators   SAMSUNG 11  26293.64

Lowest Price Products :
  133     SAMSUNG REF DC 192L RR20M182ZR2/HL 3S Refrigerators   SAMSUNG 4   16412.5
  78      SAMSUNG REF DC 192L RR20M282ZR2/NL 3S Refrigerators   SAMSUNG 2   16500
  359     SAMSUNG REF DC 212L RR22M272YS8/NL 4S Refrigerators   SAMSUNG 9   17388.89

Highest Price Products :
163     SAMSUNG REF SBS 826L RF28K9380SG/TL Refrigerators   SAMSUNG 2   218535
115     SAMSUNG REF SBS 838L RH77J90407H    Refrigerators   SAMSUNG 1   161880
1202    SAMSUNG REF SBS 680L RF60J9090SL/TL Refrigerators   SAMSUNG 4   134837.3
```

I was thinking of splitting the given input and searching in each row but the products/company have spaces then how do i approach this?

Currently this is what i have done,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sales_data.csv')
input = 'Refrigerators'

input_case = df[df['product_line'].str.contains(input) | df['brand'].str.contains(input)] 
TopPrice = input_case.nlargest(3, 'price')
BottomPrice = input_case.nsmallest(3, 'price')
TopSales = input_case.nlargest(3, 'sales')
```

How do I code for the given cases?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I'm not really sure what your asking. try skipping the extra stuff and go straight to the point. i assume your trying to split the output into multiple variables. you can try splitting by space and taking the first output as the number code. then removing the company search term name from the output. then split again and the second last number looks like count and and your last number is also available. leaving you with just the middle code

Comment: could also remove all the spaces and lowercase the output. then do the same with the search term and check to see if the output contains the search term. if that's what your going for

Comment: Thanks you for replying,  The given csv file has 6 column : product Ids, product name, product line (product category), brand , number of items sold in the last month and current prices.

Comment: I need to make a search engine where a user can enter either the company name eg:- Samsung, or product category eg - Refrigerator or both company as well as product category eg:- Samsung Refrigerator or even the product name. So i need to filter the data according to the input and the output will contain 3 products with highest price.

Comment: eg- **Input** : Samsung Refrigerators  **output** :  Highest Price Products :

163 SAMSUNG REF SBS 826L RF28K9380SG/TL Refrigerators SAMSUNG 2 218535

115 SAMSUNG REF SBS 838L RH77J90407H Refrigerators SAMSUNG 1 161880

1202 SAMSUNG REF SBS 680L RF60J9090SL/TL Refrigerators SAMSUNG 4 134837.3